# How I select any elements with same id in javascript in django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a table in Django where all the answers of a test are stored, but when I select them to compare with the response provided by the user, all the answers are the same as the first question. I know this has to do with getElementsById, which only selects the first element. But how do I select all elements of the same id in HTML?

```
{% for resposta in questao.resposta_set.all %}

    <input type="hidden" id="resposta" name="resposta" value="{{resposta.resposta}}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function mostrarSel(){
            if (getRadioValor('opcao_escolhida') == document.getElementById("resposta").value){
                alert('Resposta Correta');
            }
            else{
                alert('Resposta Incorreta');
            }
        }
        function getRadioValor(name){
            var rads = document.getElementsByName(name);
            for(var i = 0; i < rads.length; i++){
                if(rads[i].checked){
                    return rads[i].value;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

    </script>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why would someone use same `id` multiple times?

Comment: id's should be unique, instead use `class` names and use [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: You should __NEVER__ put same `id` on different elements, use `class` instead

Comment: I've already tried using gelelementsbyname, getelementsbyclassname and getelementsbytagname, and I did not succeed in any of them

Comment: `getElementsByName`, `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagname` return a list of elements. `getElementById` returns a single element. Therefore you can't simply replace `getElementById` with any of those in your `function mostrarSel`.

Answer (score 0):

In html id can't be duplicate. You can use the class, or create the dynamic id.

```
 <input type="hidden" id="resposta-{{forloop.counter}}"
        name="resposta" value="{{resposta.resposta}}">
document.getElementById("resposta-1").value which answer would you like take just keep that number.
document.getElementById("resposta-2").value
```

Comment: And javascript stays the same?

Comment: just change the id value, other code will be remain same

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same value for the attribute `id` only once in HTML document.

The `for` loop has also an attribute `forloop.counter`. A possibility would be to use this to build the ids:

```
{% for resposta in questao.resposta_set.all %}
    <input id="resposta{{ forloop.counter}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Do the same in the JavaScript code to select the right element by id.